# How to decide whether to use CSS property "will-change"

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, will-change

Recently I've dived into the topic of CSS [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations) and [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions).

I'm aware of the CSS property [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) which could be used to give a hint to the browser, that the element will change in the near future (which could improve the rendering performance).

There are several examples where developers are using `will-change` to improve the performance, e.g.:

- https://www.android.com/
- https://www.cube.eu/
- https://www.mrsandmr.com/

But the docs clearly state, that:

> Warning: will-change is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems.

So, what are essential considerations to make, whether to use `will-change` - or not?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read these articles in order. Then you will get the answer yourself.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count

Comment: Do you have a reproducible code that gives "rendering hiccups" and on what platform? So that discussion can be made. Without it people will provide just links.

Comment: @gru as mentioned by the users above, please try to create a jsfiddle with reproducible code. Also, what are your target devices? I've never had a single issue without the specific property, but will try to help out.

Comment: `will-change` creates a new compisition layer in the browser, which allows you to change certain CSS properties (notably: `transform`) without having to re-run the entire rendering pipeline. The tradeoff is speed vs memory (which also increases first content paint time) . Here's another source https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean made a great post about this that I would highly recommend you check out.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-will-change

As someone else stated, `will-change` creates a new 'layer' in the browser, so to speak. If you have multiple animations or transitions under a specific parent element, it may be a good idea to assign `will-change` to that parent element while leaving the animated child elements with their standard animations/transitions.

**Edit:** I should point out that adding `will-change` in multiple places will increase your paint time as someone else mentioned, which will decrease your site load speed.